# Links in form field show as links

Tags: html, web

I have a form, where the user fills in a web address in one of the fields. That address does not automatically turn into a link. How can I force the browser to make that into a link as soon as it is typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<a href="http://example.com">Hey I'm Your Link</a>`

Comment: I can use anchor tags after the form has been processed, and displays the results. I want the link to show as a link as soon as it's typed, before being processed.

Comment: Use javascript|jQuery as text manipulation? 
Simply bind an Event called onkeyup|onchange , and when the user have completed filling that input field, it will be anchor : http://jsfiddle.net/3um4oo4q/

Comment: This sort of works. It turns everything into links, whether it's actually a link format or not.

Comment: Of course, You need to review jQuery selectors. I picked it the informal way just for sharing the tool with you, You should visit jQuery Selectors to select more specific elements. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event when the input loses focus, or at each user keystrokes. Then parse the input value with that library : https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js
The make your link appear where you want.

For example, here is some html :

```
<script src="autolinker.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

And some javascript :

```
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  var link = Autolinker.link(this.value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<a href="'+ link + '">' + link + '</a>';
}, false);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re1wz79p/1/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <label for"url">URL: </label><input type="url" name="utl" id="url-input">
</form>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$( "#url-input" ).blur(function() {
  var cont = $(this).val();
    $( this ).css('display','none');
    $('FORM').append('<a href="'+cont+'">'+cont+'</a>');
});
```

It's very rough:

- it doesn't run validation to make sure the content is correct and is in fact a URL
- it doesn't allow going back to input for fixing/changing the URL

but, that's the general idea no?

http://jsfiddle.net/bs9oasus/

Comment: I wanted something that immediately recognizes a link, like you find in word-processing, or an email program. As soon as you leave the word, it turns blue.